# Background image is not showing in the android studio

Tags: android

I am working on a learning tutorial which needs me to add a background picture to my app. So i moved a picture to "drawable" folder and selected that file in the background properties of the particular relative layout. but the picture does not show up in my working space and yet there are no errors given. someone please help me?

Comment: post your code here..

Comment: show us some code, maybe the xml layout file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/11987047_10205766000002495_8230961180700303415_n">

</RelativeLayout> this is the xml code... help me plz

Comment: edit your question rather than adding a comment. ,,, change your background picture name to `test.png` and `@drawable/test`

Comment: Thank you mr.Blundell. help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem is with your picture name, because Resource Name must be start with character. So Rename your picture stored in drawable and start the name with character.

For example, change:

`11987047_10205766000002495_8230961180700303415_n`

to

`x11987047_10205766000002495_8230961180700303415_n`

Comment: Yeah. Finally figured it out withe the help of all of you guys.

Comment: @JanakaSampath you can set file name too long but must be started with character. Anyway, If it worked then accept my answer so that others could find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Is 11987047_10205766000002495_8230961180700303415_n your picture's name? Try to add a suffix to it, such as .jpg.
Another possible reason is that the jpg size is too big, try another smaller picture.

Comment: thank u mr.xu jifa. help much appreciated. it worked. the file name was too long

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by renaming images...

Don't use dash (-) and don't start your image name with a number.

Example: Image 'sunset-1' would not show in my work space, but image 'sunset_1' did.  Image '11sunset' did not show, but image 'x11sunset' did.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use proper formatting and remove 'Hope this helps.'